# Two Questions. Why are buttons there? Why can't I put a gray background color on the inner div?

Tags: html, css, responsive

I set the buttons to bottom:0; why are they up near the forms? Also I have a second div behind each of the last four boxes it doesn't change background-color?

[image: Screenshot of terrible product landing page]

Also what to do about the video that doesn't show? I have to put in more writing as the post is mostly code, but you could answer that too.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: green;
}

img {
  width: 150px;
  height: auto;
}

#header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-bar {
  width: 100%;
  float: right;
  background-color: #555;
  text-align: justify;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#nav-bar a.active {
  background-color: #740053;
}

.nav-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  color: coral;
}

.ul,
li {
  display: inline-block;
}

ul {
  border: solid 1px black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 20px;
}

li {
  display: block;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  color: blue;
}

#video-div {
  position: relative;
  height: 40%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 100px;
  margin-left: 250px;
}

#form {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 150px;
  margin-right: 150px;
  margin-top: 150px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border-shadow: 4px;
}

.spacer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

#email {
  margin-top: 50px;
  text-align: center
}

#submit {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
  width: 6em;
  top: 30px;
  right: 130px;
}

img {
  width: 25%;
  height: 2vh;
  float: left;
}

.box1,
.box2,
.box3,
.box4 {
  float: left;
  border: 3px solid black;
  width: 23%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: white;
  margin-right: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.innerbox {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 22%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: grey;
}

.btn {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  bottom: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 100%px) and (min-width: 99%) {}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, inital-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome    /4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <title>Product Landing</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header id="header"><img id="header-img" src="https://logos-world.net/huawei-logo/" />
    <nav id="nav-bar">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#forms">
            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-home">Form</i></a>
        </li>|
        <li>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#video">
            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-home">Resolution</i></a>
        </li>|
        <li>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#email">
            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-home">Status</i></a>
        </li>|
        <li><a class="nav-link" href="#products"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-    home">    Pricing</i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main>
    <div id="video-div">
      <video width="300" height="250" controls id="video" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TfdRmdUc12w&list=RDTfdRmdUc12w&index=1">
            </video>
    </div>
    <div id="forms">
      <form id="form" action="https://www.freecodecamp.com/email-submit">
        <label id="email-label">
             <h3>Good Resolution Packages for grabs!</h3> Email:<input id="email" type="email" placeholder="Please input your email:" name="email" required/> <input id="submit" value="Submit" type="submit">
                </label>
      </form>

    </div>
    <div class="spacer">

    </div>
    <section id="products">
      <div class="box1">
        <div class="inner-box">
          <h2>Read</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <p>
        This is the text that hold the information in the "Read" category.
      </p>
      <button class="btn">Select</button>
      </div>
      <div class="box2">
        <div class="inner-box">
          <h2>Learn</h2>
        </div>
        <p>
          This is the text that hold the information in the "Learn" category.
        </p>
        <button class="btn">Select</button>

      </div>
      <div class="box3">
        <div class="inner-box">
          <h2>Write</h2>
        </div>
        <p>
          This is the text that hold the information in the "Write" category.
        </p>
        <button class="btn">Select</button>
      </div>
      <div class="box4">
        <div class="inner-box">
          <h2>Play</h2>
        </div>
        <p>
          This is the text that hold the information in the "Play" category.
        </p>
        <button class="btn">Select</button>
      </div>
    </section>
    <footer class="footer"></footer>
  </main>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The buttons are positioned absolute and because you've not created any stacking contexts they're postioned against the viewport. When you scroll they move with the scroll as that's one of the properties of that positioning rule.

The background color does not show in your second div as you've declared it as 'innerbox' in your css file but as 'inner-box' in your html.

As far as your video goes, use the youtube-verified way of embedding from their site e.g. `<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/TfdRmdUc12w" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>` and you'll see it works.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a result like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLzwv.png)

**Wrong class in styles** - in markup class (inner-box), and in styles ( .innerbox )

And then there's this. There are still errors in the styles
**1) You don't apply the style to any class, or you haven't copied it**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1wjy.png)
2) **That style does not exist** ( #form{ border-shadow: 4px}), есть ( box-shadow )**
3) `@media (max-width: 100%px) and (min-width: 99%)`

**Make up your mind here, either 100% or 100px**

Comment: I'm really struggling to become good at designing webpages and not making mistakes like above, or even finding solutions to anything.

Comment: Then I suggest you learn bootstrap, it's indispensable in the design process anyway.

Comment: Try Kevin Powell's css & html crash course. It's free and should get you started. With regard to bootstrap it makes some things easier but you still have to learn the basics too. Good luck https://www.kevinpowell.co/courses/